# Shutdown an ec2 instance after finishing computing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I’m coding a chess engine for a project at school and i need more computing power than my pc can offer.
So i turned to AWS and especially EC2. I want to test different algorithms.

I know how to start the instance and how to begin the computing on the instance but as soon as the computing is finished, I would like to send automatically the data files on s3 (i know the command but not how to automatically execute it) and shutdown the instance to avoid paying for nothing.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: After you power off your ec2 instance, it will be stopped by default. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#Using_ChangingInstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior

Comment: Yes but how do i power off the instance automatically, because that’s my question...

Comment: what do you mean by <automatically> ofcourse you have to run some code for doing your  tasks like uplodaing your data files to s3 and after you done that operation you can shutdown the executing shutdown command. When you ask how do you get that code inside the machine , you can use [userdata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) for that.
as per the documentation link pointed by @jellycsc when you call shutdown, your instance stops and you stop paying for that.

Comment: I mean : i’m coding my engine in python so i would like to implement in my program (after the chess computing has finished) the code to send the data files on s3 and then the code to shutdown the instance. It should be automatic so i don’t need to reconnect to the instance to shut it down, because i dont know how long my code will run.

Comment: yes, you can simply call <os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")> from the python code or whichever method suit you to call shutdown, post uploading files to s3.

Comment: Might be useful: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by samtoddler on Jan 11, 2021 :
a call to os.shutdown() after the computing provided what I wanted !

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32219446)

Comment: What if the answer comes from a comment on my post directly ? I specifically added an answer to point that out…

Answer (score 0):

You mention your script is in python, in that case probably you could execute it with AWS Lambda and configure rules in CloudWatch Events Rules to define the time to run the script. Consider the maximum time that Lambda allows is 15 minutes so if it is not suitable for your case you can check ECS Fargate Scheduled Tasks to run the process at the defined time and then delete the container.